# Showing another HTML page inside my own page

Tags: iframe, object

I keep hearing that iframes have been depreciated and object's are the best way to achieve this now, however most articles that state this are 3 or so years old.  With the current technologies and frameworks what is the best way to show another page (from a different domain) inside my own html page?

Answer (score 2):

Use common sense, most of all! If you include the contents of another website in your own site, you could be violating someone's copyright! Even if you just display the other site in an iframe. So make sure you have permission before including another site in yours.

Answer (score 0):

An iframe is still an acceptable way of solving this problem. you may need a p3p policy though (for cookies).